# Encountered an error while trying to use a php framework

Tags: php

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\E-LAMAX\app\libraries\Core.php on line 18
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or
> view not found: 1146 Table 'lamax.settings' doesn't exist in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\E-LAMAX\app\libraries\Database.php:66 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\E-LAMAX\app\libraries\Database.php(66):
> PDOStatement->execute() #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\E-LAMAX\app\libraries\Database.php(77):
> Database->execute() #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\E-LAMAX\app\models\Setting.php(17): Database->single()
> #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\E-LAMAX\app\controllers\Pages.php(18): Setting->getSettings() #4
> C:\xampp\htdocs\E-LAMAX\app\libraries\Core.php(45): Pages->index() #5
> C:\xampp\htdocs\E-LAMAX\public\index.php(4): Core->__construct() #6
> {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\E-LAMAX\app\libraries\Database.php on
> line 66

Comment: It would help if you included more details, including the framework you are using and the code where the error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pointing to a database error: Table 'lamax.settings' doesn't exist.

Make sure you have that table in your database